# Stuck in grub rescue after I tried to upgrade to Windows 8

Tags: grub2, partitioning, windows-7, windows-8

So I was using Windows 7 and the latest version of Ubuntu on dual boot. I decided to remove my Ubuntu OS so I deleted my Ubuntu partition in 'windows disk management' and alloted the free space to create a new disk.

After that I tried to upgrade my windows 7 to 8 using the windows upgrade tool. The ISO was downloaded and was installing. After some time when the OS had to restart the computer to complete the remaining progress it got struck in grub rescue.

Nothing is helping me out to get out of it. I can't even access anything. I tried the solution given on some forums
Where I change the file system to by set prefix = (hdx,Y)/boot)

But the problem is all my file systems are unknown when I try to open it through the 'ls' command. So no file system is allowing me to boot it to normal mode.

Comment: I have 6 file systems shown! (hd0) (hd0,msdos6)  (hd0,msdos5)  (hd0,msdos3)  (hd0,msdos2)  (hd0,msdos1) but all the file system shown unknown when I try to open them in ls command

Comment: You need to use a bootable Windows Installation or recovery media, preferably Windows 8 since that's the one you're in the process of upgrading to, boot from it and follow instructions for repair. Detailed instructions are available everywhere on the net but are off-topic here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into live window USB.

Next>Repair your computer>Troubleshoot.>Advanced options.>Command Prompt
and type these commands

```
Bootrec /fixMbr

Bootrec /fixBoot

exit
```

And you are done!

To repair your grub menu form live USB.
This will help you.

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Actually it's the the way around, *how to recover Windows bootloader after deleting Ubuntu partitions (where Grub had its data)*...

Comment: @Celtic Thanks for pointing out, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but I think we shouldn't be answering this questions here. There's a SE site for Windows and this is entirely about Windows.

Comment: I'm sorry! @celticWarrior. I'm a noob when it comes to such stuff! This website popped out first when I searched my problem on Google.So i figured this was it! Thank you